# Count number of object in another object , javascript-json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

There seems to have many question asked similar on counting number of element already but I am failing to implement them with mine problem.

After jquery ajax I get JSON data returned which looks something like this

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object , xxxx:"asdf" ,yyyy:"asdf", zzzz:"asdf"}
```

I want to get number of **object** between this { } braces ( not counting those xxx,yyy element )

I tried `.length` which doesn't work

I also tried using this [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array) but that return the number of element in each object. I just want the number of object

Thank You

Comment: If it's not just a coincidence that the objects are the ones with numeric property names you could, assuming you have the top-level object in a variable, `obj`, do this: `for (var i=0; i in obj; i++) { /* use obj[i] */ }` - I don't really know why you need to count them, but obviously after that loop finishes `i` will be the count...

Comment: Thank You this works well , enough to accept it as answer :)

Comment: OK, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not just a coincidence that the objects are the ones with numeric property names, and the numeric properties count up sequentially, you could do something like this:

```
var obj = { /* your object here */ }
for (var i=0; i in obj; i++) {
   // use obj[i] for something
}
// i is now equal to the number of numeric properties
```

This works because as soon as `i` is high enough that you've run out of properties the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) will return `false`. Feel free to use [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) instead if you prefer.

Obviously this is a specialised solution that doesn't test the type of the different properties at all. (To actually test the type see elclanrs' solution - and either way read the page he linked to.)

Comment: yeah its object are the only one with numeric property names.. and therefore i think this answer will be easiest and best to my problem. Counting won't require also :)

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs. When I noticed the pattern in the OP's object's properties this just kind of seemed right, bearing in mind all of the "this will only work if..." conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var json = { 0: {}, 1: {}, xxxx: "asdf", yyyy: "asdf", zzzz: "asdf" };

function typeOf( obj ) {
  return ({}).toString.call( obj )
    .match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

var total = 0;
for ( var o in json ) {
  if ( typeOf( json[o] ) == 'object' ) {
    total++;
  }
}

console.log( total ); //=> 2
```

Everything is an object in JavaScript. The `typeof` operator is misleading and won't work in this case. You can use the `typeOf` function above that I extracted from this blog post: [Fixing the JavaScript typeof operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/) (worth reading). There are other ways of doing it but this seems like the most straightforward.

Comment: +1. The page you linked to is definitely worth reading. Nice one.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the explanation and the page u linked to :)

Answer (score 0):

Say that the entire json is in a variable called `json`:

```
var total_objects = 0;
$.each(json, function () {
   if (typeof this == 'object') {
      total_objects++;
   }
});
```

However, I am curious as to why you would need to know this.

Comment: I wanted to know this because I want to run an another loop to print each element in each of those object(not sure that is there another recommended way to do the same) :S

Comment: Why do you need to count them first? Just run the print loop.

Comment: This won't work. Strings are objects, arrays are objects, functions are objects...etc. `typeof` is misleading.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't seems to work...it count everything...I have 2 object inside and 36 of those xxx , yyy element... and therefore total_objects is giving me 38  :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customized version from the code of this question [Length of Javascript Object (ie. Associative Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array) and check for element's type using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator and count only those which are an `object` (or an `array`).

```
Object.sizeObj = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof key[obj] === 'object' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the count of those elements which are an object
var objectsCount = Object.sizeObj(myArray);
```